# Bash cannot access a variable inside function when running as another user

Tags: linux, bash

I have the below script and I am trying to access `logtime` variable when calling the function as userA but the `$logtime` inside the function is not getting the value. This works when I am not switching the user.

```
logtime=`date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S"`

runcommand()
{
echo " Log time is $logtime"
}

export -f runcommand
su userA -c "bash -c runcommand >>  compile-$logtime.txt"
```

`$logtime` is not getting assigned inside the function when called as userA

```
cat compile-2022-11-07_121225.txt
Log time is
```

Comment: If `su` didn't reset the environment, all manner of attacks would be possible across a privilege boundary.

Comment: `export logtime`

Comment: You didn't `export` logtime. I don't know if there's a sane way to reliably persist it across `su` boundary, anyway; my suggestion would be to save this as a script, or at the very least include the assignment as a local variable inside the function.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I think `su` only resets environment if called as `su ... - ...`

Comment: @jhnc, you're right; without `-l` or `-`, most environment variables (excluding `USER`, `HOME` and `SHELL`) are let be, at least on a BSD-style `su`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy ah, yes, on ubuntu the manpage says: *Note that su in all cases uses PAM (pam_getenvlist(3)) to do the final environment modification. Command-line options such as --login and --preserve-environment affect the environment before it is modified by PAM*

Comment: you could also rewrite the function to take an argument: eg. `runcommand(){ local logtime=$1; ...; }` and invoke as: `... bash -c runcommand "$logtime" ...`

Answer (score 3):

`declare -f funcname` emits source that, when evaluated, recreates your function.

`declare -p varname` emits source that, when evaluated, recreates your variable.

These both can be added into the content you run on the other side of a privilege boundary. Thus:

```
sudo -u userA bash <<EOF
$(declare -f runcommand)
$(declare -p logtime)
runcommand >>"compile-$logtime.txt" # note it's the outer shell expanding $logtime
EOF
```

...or, without the heredoc (the switch from double to single quotes lets the *inner* shell expand `$logtime` here, contrary to the above):

```
sudo -u userA bash -c "$(declare -f runcommand); $(declare -p logtime)"'; runcommand >>compile-$logtime.txt'
```

---

If you do stick with `su`, though, the easiest fix is just to `export logtime`.

```
export logtime
export -f runcommand
su userA -c 'bash -c runcommand >>"compile-$logtime.txt"'
```

This is generally silly, though -- you have some other shell invoking bash, so the real invocation looks like `sh -c 'bash -c runcommand'`. Taking out the shell in the middle makes life easier for everyone.

Comment: sudo -u userA bash -c "$(declare -f runcommand); $(declare -p logtime)"'; runcommand >>compile-$logtime.txt'

This worked

Comment: @MathewShiju, glad to hear it! If you consider the question solved, click the checkbox by the answer.

Answer (score -2):

Variables will remain inside of the running scritp, even accessing them from the current user, won't be possible.

you may try to first source the script file, then execute it

Comment: Sourcing the file isn't optimal -- you can get two different ideas of the time based on when the parent process set `logtime` vs when the child process does; it'll work _most_ of the time, but that one time a second boundary is crossed the application's logs are divided into two different files.